# how to post to all friends in wall One time facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, api

I want to publish to all people to connect through application Publish all his friends in the wall, this code only publishes its wall What needs to change or add to it will take to his friends list and will publish them in the wall through app

please help me

```
    require "../settings.php";
    require '../src/facebook.php';
    require "../fbaccess.php";
    require "web_config.php";


    //user data from database
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,user_access_token,user_access_token_expire FROM data_table");

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $user_id = $data['user_id'];
    $accessToken = $data['user_access_token'];
    $accessTokenExpire = $data['user_access_token_expire'];


    try {
                $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user_id/feed", 'post', array(
                    'message' => "",
                    'link'    => '',
                    'picture' => '',
                    'name'    => 'iOS Apps & Games',
                    'description'=> ''
                    )
                );
                //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the base url
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Your English is really bad. I suggest that you write the question in your native language and use Google Translate to transcribe to English.

Comment: I want to publish to all people to connect through application

Publish all his friends in the wall, this code only publishes its wall

What needs to change or add to it will take to his friends list and will publish them in the wall through apps

Comment: That translation is not as clear as I had hoped... Maybe someone else will understand. Sorry.

Comment: This script publishes my wall,

How do I do that he will publish in the wall of my friends?

Comment: your code looks fine. what error are you receiving?

Comment: actually your code is not fine, *message* and *link* should not be blank

Comment: Yeah I know, it publishes only my wall

If the id of one of my friends there in database so that it also publishes


I want it to automatically take all my friends list and will publish them

Comment: Facebook will not allow you to do that. It will detect that you are spamming and block your application.

Comment: If you post something to your __own__ wall, your friends will see it anyway (at least those that are interested in what you post on your wall). So that should be enough already, without the need to spam to everyone’s personal wall.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get all of your friends user ids:

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()))
```

However, if you try posting to all your friends, Facebook will block your application. What you can do instead is send your friends **Requests**.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I want to put it and I know that apps will be blocked anyway where I should put this code?